# Breeze Custom Actions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, breeze

I've been using BreezeJS in a number of projects for a while now, and I have to say that in most ways, it makes your life MUCH easier, which is why I keep coming back to it. However, I seem to consistently run into a scenario where it falls completely flat, and I cant seem to find any "correct" way of working around this issue.

Let me explain. One of the best things about BreezeJS is that it follow this UoW pattern that allows you to save entities using the saveChanges method of the entity manager, like EF.

However this is also a part of the problem, because as you develop more and more sophisticated application, I sometimes feel this approach is not always appropriate. I find that often I have:

1. Operations that doesn't really involve creating entities on the client, but rather involve executing an action on the web api that may result in the creation of various entities or other forms of state on the server, that should then be send back to the client.
2. Operations that involve entities with properties, that cannot be saved because some of them are private to the server, and should not be put on the client (often solved with a JsonIgnore for the client, but comes with issues when you start persisting the given entity again)

I feel that there is one thing that could solve these issues relatively easily, and it is a concept that already exists in OData: Actions. Actions that can be performed globally, on entity sets or on specific entities and then return either custom objects or entities that will be directly tracked by BreezeJS.

Currently, I find myself doing the following workaround (which I don't know if is appropriate):

- Make a "Resource" action on the BreezeController that represents an action rather than an an actual resource. This takes in a custom parameter object and returns a non-entity object, that may contain actual entities (as described under "Cool Breezes" with the Lookups, because these will then be track by BreezeJS)
- Use the "ajaxpost" breeze lab to allow querying a resource with a POST instead of a GET so any sort of arguments can be passed in.

Is there a more appropriate way of accomplishing something like this? Are there future plans to support custom actions?

An approach I have seen to solve this type of operation, is to simply make these sort of operations "around" the breeze api controller. That is, simply using an ApiController that has nothing to do with breeze. But I kinda feel this defeats the purpose of breeze, because then, if the operation results in the creation or deletion of entities, you must start tracking them by yourself on the client, by either creating them locally, or by issuing another breeze query to go get them. This really gets tiresome if you need a lot of these types of operations.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue myself.

Answer (score 1):

I’m struggling with the same issue myself. I have an app that uses breeze to store trades in a SQL database and after the trade is stored, another user can use the app to send the trade to a backend trading system. I created an OData action to do the import to the external trading system so I can do a post to /trades(123)/ImportTrade.  When I get the metadata for the service using /$metadata it sees that the trades entity has this action (it's in the metadata). 
I was hoping that breeze would see this in the metadata and create a method on the trades entity to do a post to my OData action, but it does not. This would be a great feature if it was added to breeze (exposing OData actions as methods on entities).

As a workaround I have extended the breeze entity myself with a custom method that does the post to /trades(???)/ImportTrade. 
It would be great if breeze could handle this for us!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach using ajax post is a good way to do thouse kind of things...
You can also make your own context by inheriting from BreezeContext that has nothing to do with a DB, and do your actions there with out saving the entites and still get the result back as a non tracked object or entities.

If you create a new entity on the server (not always a good idea with breeze, but still can still be done) you have to make sure that breeze will still generate the temp keys for that entity.
You can use the temp key generator or just delete the primary keys of the non tracked object.
You can use the metadata of that entity type in order to get it's primary key properties and then delete them using javascript like so: delete obj[prop]
then use createEntity with the non tracked entity that doesn't have primary keys.
Breeze will then generate the primary keys for you and your all set.

I also hope that Breeze will address the need to do custom actions that may return a custom non tracked object in a more intuitive way

Hope this helps

Comment: What do you mean by inheriting from "BreezeContext"?

Comment: i mean you can make your own class that implements BreezeContextProvider functions like SaveChanges in order to create a custome logic and then call make an instance of that that class and call it's SaveChanges function with your save bundle like you would normaly do with the native context provider